# NoSQL conception with Cassandra - how to insert?

Tags: triggers, nosql, cassandra, insertion

I have to evaluate the opportunity to manage some data in a NoSQL base. I chose Cassandra (Apache) to do this.

I created a base:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE cv WITH REPLICATION = {'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1};
```

with only one little table:

```
CREATE TABLE element (Id_el int, name varchar, Fk int, PRIMARY KEY(Id_el));
```

-When trying to insert sample values:

```
INSERT INTO element (Id_el, name, Fk) VALUES (1, 'smith', 2);
```

Cassandra.bat answer me:

```
Trigger directory doesn't exist, please create it and try again.
```

-When I go int:
C:\var\lib\cassandra\data\cv\
there is element directory, but it is void - not even a schema of table.

P.S.:
-I know there is no foreign key in NoSQL. It is only to evaluated the opportunity to make some Evolved requests in a columns oriented NoSQL.
-I have made other researches on Internet, with few disparate results. Also red french tutorials on développez.net.

Comment: First, can you make sure `conf/triggers` exists?  This is what the error message refers to.  And secondly, your schema tables will leave in the system keyspace, not your user defined one.  So this would be under `c:\var\lib\cassandra\data\system\schema_*` in your case.